# Empty string doesn't match .*?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match anything that goes between BEGIN and END, with respect to spaces and newlines.

I.E. I have the following text:

> ```
> BEGIN
>
> END
>
> BEGIN
>    a
> END
> ```

And I want to write a regexp that would return two matches: '' and 'a'. Currently I have this:

`/\s*BEGIN\s*\n(.*?)\n\s*END\s*\n/sg`

However, this one gives only one match:

```
END

BEGIN
    a
```

You see where the problem lies: the first BEGIN is paired with second END. I want it to be paired with first END. It looks like

```
.*?
```

is not matched by empty string - i.e. it matches greedily.

Comment: I don't know about Perl, but I tried this in C# and it worked.

Comment: `.*?` *does* match the empty string: `perl -We '$_ = ""; print "match" if /.*?/;'`

Comment: I'm getting the same results as you. `.*?` does match "" but is still being greedy, apparently.

Comment: `.*?` isn't greedy, but `\s*` is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl non-greedy problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000820/perl-non-greedy-problem)

Answer (score 8):

```
 222224466888AA                         Expected
"BEGIN\n\nEND\n\nBEGIN\n   a\nEND\n"
 22222334455555555555555555566888AA     Got

 111 22222 333 44 55555 66 777 888 999 AA    
/\s* BEGIN \s* \n (.*?) \n \s* END \s* \n/xsg
```

As you can see, the first thing that doesn't match as expected is the `\s*` after `BEGIN`. You want that `\s*` to match any whitespace except newlines, which can be done using `[^\S\n]*`.

```
/^ [^\S\n]* BEGIN [^\S\n]* \n (.*?) \n [^\S\n]* END [^\S\n]* \n/xsmg
```

---

As you can see, the non-greediness modifier is prone to failure when used to avoid matching something. If you wanted something more robust, you'd use the following idiom:

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`

This would give you

```
/
   ^ [^\S\n]* BEGIN [^\S\n]* \n
   ( (?:(?! ^ [^\S\n]* (?: BEGIN | END ) [^\S\n]* \n ).)* ) \n
   [^\S\n]* END [^\S\n]* \n
/xsmg
```

Comment: Personal preference of modifiers aside, the negative lookahead makes intent more apparent IMO, as you explicitly don't want to encounter the next "BEGIN" or "END".

Comment: That's what I'm saying, that `.*?` does not show intent -- while a negative lookahead, which you have since removed from your answer, does.

Comment: @Wiseguy, oh, I misread, sorry. Yeah, I removed it because I came up with an alternate solution, and using the lookahead just made it more complicated. I'll readd a mention.

Comment: nice way to represent what happened

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $str = "BEGIN

END

BEGIN
   a
END";
my $re = qr~BEGIN\s+(.*?)\s+END~;
my (@m) = $str =~ /$re/sg;
dump@m;
```

**output:**

```
("", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this website, which seems to describe your issue:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Based on the information on that page, I would suggest trying something along the lines `BEGIN\n?([^\r\n])\n?END`

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint by @Wiseguy, it was the greedy whitespace matching that caused the problem. When I converted them to non-greedy, it started working in all cases except the one where the is literally nothing between BEGIN and END:

```
BEGIN
END
```

I solved it by adding a non-capturing group:

```
/BEGIN\s*\n(?:(.*?)\n)??\s*END\s*\n/sg
```